# Get information about my PSU

Tags: power-management

I want to know what kind of power supply I have and what wattage it has. I tried:

```
sudo dmidecode -t 39
```

but that didn't show any specs. What do I need to do? I am on Ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should open your case and read all the data you are interested in at the power supply only or at the laptop adapter because power supplies don't have signals(no data bus) to "tell" about themselves to the any device like mainboard.